# CakePHP: User data saveAll silently fails?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have a User model which hasMany Instrument and Genre. The Instrument and Genre save when I use the code below:

```
$this->User->saveAll($this->data, array(
                'fieldList' => array('User', 'UserInstrument', 'Genre')))
        )
```

But the User doesn't. All of the invalidFields arrays are empty in my debugger (`User, UserInstrument, Genre, UserGenre, Instrument`).

One weird thing I'm noticing, though, is that in here:

```
public function beforeSave() {
        // get the password reset
        if(isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password_reset'])) {
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $this->data[$this->alias]['password_reset'];
            unset($this->data[$this->alias]['password_reset']);
        }
        // get rid of the password confirm
        if(isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password_confirm'])) {
            unset($this->data[$this->alias]['password_confirm']);
        }
        // hash the password
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I am unsetting the `password_reset` and `password_confirm`, but after the save is done, these fields magically appear back in `$this->data['User']` (probably re-grabbed from `$_POST`). But if there was an error saving then the `saveAll` would return false. I have nothing in my error log either.

Any ideas as to why this is silently failing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took out `fieldList`. Not the safest solution, but this was just causing more of a hassle than it was worth.

Answer (score 1):

if your purpose is to use hashing for newly created users, please consult [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html)

Especially the beforeSave function which is simply just

```
public function beforeSave() {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Please understand that in cakephp, if you include a field that is actually NOT in the datatable for the models, that field would be ignored. So you need not actually do an unset for your password_reset and password_confirm fields.

As for saving associated records and using fieldList, I noticed that you did not explicitly state the fields that you want to save in the fieldList key of the array.

Moreover, you stated that User hasMany Instrument and User hasMany Genre.

Please use the saveAssociated way.

Prepare your data like this in the controller:

```
$this->data['Instrument'] = array(
    array('instrument_field1'=>'v1',
           'instrument_field2' => 'v2',
         ),// first instrument
    array('instrument_field1' => 'v1',
          'instrument_field2' => 'v2')// second instrument
);

$this->data['Genre'] = array(
    array('field1'=>'v1',
           'field2' => 'v2',
         ),// first genre
    array('field1' => 'v1',
          'field2' => 'v2')// second genre
);
```

OR in your forms you do something like this:

```
$this->Form->input('Instrument.0.field1'); // for the first instrument 
$this->Form->input('Instrument.1.field1'); // for the second instrument
```

Comment in my answer if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Hi Kimsia, thanks for the response. In my `beforeSave()`, I am accommodating for password hashing **as well as** password resetting, which is available when the user is editing their account.

As for the Instrument and Genre, those save properly. I will try adding the specific fields to the `fieldList` and see if they save properly, and then comment back here.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Hi @Garrett, this is how I usually do things for User Creation and User Update.

For creating new users, I tend to have a separate method called createNewUserDuringSignup

Inside this method I ensure I have $this->create(); and other related things for new users.

For update password, I have a separate method as well.

As for the beforeSave, I hash the password like you except I add in a isset to ensure the field exists.
I will also hash a field called new_password which is for resetting of passwords.

Let me know if you want a more detailed explanation using actual code. I will do up a page

Comment: so do you need a more detailed explanation?

Comment: The `Instrument` and `Genre` can save but the `User` cannot. I tried removing all validation, but that didn't work either. Adding the specific fields to the `fieldList` array didn't work, either :(

Comment: a) did you try my method? if no, 
b) then did you remember to put a return true for your beforeSave in User?